# RecyclerView on a fragment

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, fragment

i am trying to add a recyclerview on a fragment
fragments code:

```
public class MediaPlayerController extends Fragment{
    private static final String TAG = "MediaPlayerController";

private RecyclerView recyclerViewb;
private RecycleViewAdapter myAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> myRecordings = new ArrayList<>();
//private DBHelper dbHelper;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: started");
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.media_player_area, container, false);

    recyclerViewb = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewXml);
    //dbHelper = new DBHelper(v.getContext(), null, null, 1);

    myRecordings.add("hau");
    myRecordings.add("hau2");
    myRecordings.add("hau3");
    myRecordings.add("hau4");
    myRecordings.add("ha5");
    myRecordings.add("hau23");
    myRecordings.add("ha31u");
    myRecordings.add("haudsa");

    System.out.println("what does this print?"+myRecordings);

    myAdapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(v.getContext(), myRecordings);

    recyclerViewb.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    recyclerViewb.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(v.getContext()));

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: returned");
    return v;
}
```

in the logs i see that that it doesn't even get to the RecycleViewAdapter sections of code at all the fragment is completely blank
i get not errors as well

```
public class RecycleViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    private static final String TAG = "RecycleViewAdapter";


private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<String> mRecName = new ArrayList<>();

public RecycleViewAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> mRecName) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mRecName = mRecName;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder: i am here");
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_row_recycle, parent, false);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: called");
    holder.recTxt.setText(mRecName.get(position).toString());


    holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "sas gamaw", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    RelativeLayout parentLayout;
    TextView recTxt;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        recTxt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recTextView);
        parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parentLayoutXml);
    }
}
```

}

in the logs it only displays oncreateView started and the myRecordings arraylist

- onCreateView: started
- I/System.out: what does this print?[hau, hau2,    hau3, hau4, ha5,
  hau23, ha31u, haudsa]
- MediaPlayerController:    onCreateView: returned

i can't think of what is going wrong :/ please help out

i also want to add that i am fairly new to android studio thanks

Comment: i fixed it i forgot to return the size of the arraylist in @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code problem it is in Recycler Adapter in getItemCount() method,
You don't return any Item , you must change it to :

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mRecName.size();
}
```